# Crash after FIX::SessionSettings initiator

Tags: c++, crash, quickfix

I want to initialize a QuickFix initiator and I used the following code:

```
ExtLogger.Out(MTLogOK, L"FIXExchangeAPI::initialize start");
std::string filename = "FileSettings.cfg";//cfgFileName
ExtLogger.Out(MTLogOK, L"FIXExchangeAPI::initialize filename");
FIX::SessionSettings settings(filename);
ExtLogger.Out(MTLogOK, L"FIXExchangeAPI::initialize settings");
FIX::FileStoreFactory storeFactory(settings);
FIX::ScreenLogFactory logFactory(settings);
_socketInitiator = new FIX::SocketInitiator(*this, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);
ExtLogger.Out(MTLogOK, L"FIXExchangeAPI::initialize true");
```

It works inside the debugger but, when I try to use it inside an executable (I'm working on Windows) the .exe file crashes after the line:

```
FIX::SessionSettings settings(filename);
```

My QuickFix configuration file is:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=1
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=N
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1


[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=123
TargetCompID=Coinbase
SocketConnectPort=4198
DefaultApplVerID=9
ResetOnLogon=Y
Password=password
DataDictionary=FIX42.xml
```

What is happening?

Comment: Don't you have a crash log of some kind? Otherwise it is only guesswork.

Comment: `00000065`bcd6f300 00007ff6`5fcfcdae : 000001e6`d337b6c0 00000065`bcd6f6a8 00000065`bcd6f6a8 cccccccc`cccccccc : SampleGateway64!FIXExchangeAPI::initialize+0x9e
00000065`bcd6f680 00007ff6`5fd6bfbe : 000001e6`d3985700 000001e6`d3987560 cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc : SampleGateway64!CGateway::Initialize+0xee`

Comment: Last in call stack:
`00000065`bcd6be80 00007ffa`665d10bd : 00000065`bcd6bf90 00000065`bcd6bf88 00000000`00000024 cccccccc`cccccccc : ucrtbased!__crt_stdio_output::output_processor<wchar_t,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<wchar_t>,__crt_stdio_output::format_validation_base<wchar_t,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<wchar_t> > >::process+0x114`

Comment: `ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005`

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17169463/4962355

Comment: I am logging, because program crashed ,if a don't do it ,programm was crashed does not matter. If you mean problem with log?

Comment: Now i am using .exe release mode and it works ok, but  .exe mode Debug it crushed, i don't understand that

Comment: I solved my problem, app don't see cfg file, i set full path and it works