# Exit code: 3221225477 working with tdbc::mysql

Tags: tcl, mysql-connector

testing this script (parameters are not real, of course):

```
package require tdbc::mysql

tdbc::mysql::connection create test_conn -user test_admin -passwd test_passw -db test -host www.test.com -port 3306
set consulta "SELECT * FROM entes"
set sentencia [test_conn prepare $consulta ]
$sentencia foreach row {
puts $row
}
$sentencia close
test_conn close
```

I get this

> Exit code: 3221225477

However, using this

```
puts [test_conn evaldirect $consulta ]
```

i get the right lists.
So, is something wrong with "prepare" or have i made a mistake ?
Thanks,

Alejandro

Comment: It definitely shouldn't crash!

Comment: I can't debug to c level but the problem is related to dll files. After testing several versions of libmariadb.dll, i can confirm that only 3.1.17 works, both 3.2.7 and 3.3.1 fails.

Comment: Converting to hex, that code is `c0000005` and that's an [Access Violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168982/exception-error-c0000005-in-vc). Which is definitely a bug (see https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbcmysql for where you might proceed from there). I don't have the tooling to hunt it, nor access to a MySQL database to even attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes, i've created a ticket reporting this problem.