# tdbc::mysql "allrows" and "prepare" statements segmentation faults on mariadb-libs above 10.5.11

Tags: segmentation-fault, mariadb, tcl

My problem:

tdbcmyslq version 1.1.3 works fine only with mariadb-libs and mariadb-clients up to 10.5.11
On higher versions of mariadb-libs **allrows** and **prepare** statements make segfault.

My code:

```
package require tdbc::mysql
namespace import ::tdbc::mysql::*
connection create db -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3306 -passwd mypass -user root -database mydb

#working on all configs
db evaldirect "select product_id from product_to_category where category_id=555"

#seg fault  on mariadb-libs above 10.5.11
db allrows  { select * from category_description }
db prepare  { select * from category_description }
```

This code segfaults on latest Arch linux distribution,and latest Alpine linux server with
mariadb-client and mariadb-libs  10.6.9.
And it works fine if i downgrade mariadb-libs to 10.5.11

Pls can u test this, and if its bug, bugreport it, or tell me how to bugreport.

Upd:

I allready found where to bugreport

https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbcmysql/tktview?name=79e85de788

Comment: Someone has created a bug report: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbcmysql/tktview?name=79e85de788

Comment: That was me sir.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73380461/exit-code-3221225477-working-with-tdbcmysql). There are definitely some issues with the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug should be fixed in tdbc::mysql 1.1.5.

A workaround is to install the MySQL client libraries alongside the MariaDB ones.  On a Debian-based system,

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient21
```

would do it.

This oughtn't to interfere with MariaDB client libraries, and tdbc::mysql runs fine with a MySQL client against a MariaDB server (or I'd have noticed this problem a lot sooner!)

Answer (score 0):

i've post here in stackoverflow a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73380461/exit-code-3221225477-working-with-tdbcmysql), later in [comp.lang.tcl](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/vPLkVXR_B9E) and finally open a ticket in [tdbc::mysql](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbcmysql/info/78b1ea5622dc2f1a):

> Win32 - tdbc 1.1.2 - tcl/tk 8.6.11
>
> Hello, testing this script (parameters are not real, of course):

```
package require tdbc::mysql
tdbc::mysql::connection create test_conn -user test_admin -passwd \  
test_passw -db test -host www.test.com -port 3306
set consulta "SELECT * FROM entes"
set sentencia [test_conn prepare $consulta ]
$sentencia foreach row {
    puts $row 
}
$sentencia close
test_conn close
```

> I get this
>
> > Exit code: 3221225477
>
> However, using this
>
> puts [test_conn evaldirect $consulta ]
>
> i get the right lists.
>
> After testing several versions of libmariadb.dll, i can confirm that
> only 3.1.17 works, both 3.2.7 and 3.3.1 fails.

Later i've tested a "fixed" 1.1.4 version, however didn't work either for me.

After debug this using my humble C expertise, i'm traced the problem to this line :

```
if (Tcl_GetCommandInfo(interp, "::tcl::build-info", &info)) {
```

being the command tcl::build-info added after tcl 8.7.

For all that, i've post a comment in other [ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbcmysql/info/430e4ff9df6e5077):

> My test with 8.6.xx fails, however this seems caused by new features
> in 8.7.

> I can't confirm it because all Win32 binary distributions are
> 8.6.xx

I hope someone can check and fix this in the tdbc::mysql.

Saludos,

Alejandro

Comment: Will be fixed in tdbc::mysql 1.1.5.